# How would I run a function when the compose button is clicked?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm working on a Gmail add-on that adds some text to the bottom every time an email is opened. I'd like to make it so that the user doesn't have to click the add-on every time, instead it would just run a function as soon as the Gmail compose opens (so not using a selectAction). Is this at all possible and if it is, how?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you are saying then I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, if you are using [`compose actions`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui) to create your Add-on it states how the add-on will interact with the user when composing an email:

> The first way is to start composing a new draft or reply while the add-on is already open.
>
> The second way is to start the add-on while composing a draft.
>
> Either case causes the add-on to execute the corresponding compose trigger function, defined in the add-on manifest. The compose trigger function builds the compose UI for that compose action, which Gmail then displays to the user.

So in each case the user will still need to be running the add on.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)